# Angular: Unable to route

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I'm new to Angular. Please excuse if this question is naive.

This is my HTML:

```
<tr *ngFor="let transaction of transactions; let i = index">
        <td>{{transaction.name}}</td>
        <td><a [routerLink]="['/transactions', {name: transaction.name, currentVersion: transaction.currentVersion}]">{{transaction.currentVersion}}</a></td>
        <td>{{transaction.month}}</td>
        <td>{{transaction.status}}</td>
        <td><a>{{transaction.prevVersion}}</a></td>
        <td>{{transaction.subDate}}</td>
        <td>{{transaction.dueDate}}</td>
        <td>{{transaction.lastUpdatedBy}}</td>
        <td>
          <span class="fa fa-check"></span>
          <span class="fa fa-remove"></span>
        </td>
      </tr>
```

And this is my router config:

```
{
    path: 'transactions',
    component: TransactionsComponent,
    canActivate: [CanActivateAuthGuardService],
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        component: ViewTransactionsComponent
      },
      {
        path: ':id',
        component: TransactionDetailsComponent
      },
      {
        path: 'create-transaction',
        component: CreateTransactionComponent
      }
    ]
  }
```

I'm trying to route to a details component with an object as a route param. But it's not working.

Below is a snippet of my browser's navbar.

[image: Browser's Navigation Bar]

Please help me with this.

Comment: Can you try `path: '/transactions'` instead of `path: 'transactions'`?

Comment: do you need object as query params? if so then try

 <td><a [routerLink]="['/transactions']" [queryParams]='{name: transaction.name, currentVersion: transaction.currentVersion}'>{{transaction.currentVersion}}</a></td>

Comment: can you post the app.component html which contains your <router-outlet> and also place holder for chiild router outlet

Comment: @AntonLee, thanks man. I used query params and it worked. By the way, can't we pass object literals as route params?